# Showing the limit does not exist using sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Let,

$$f(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{cc} -2x + 1, & x<0\\ x^2 + x, & x>0\end{array}\right.$$

Give an explicit sequence $\{x_n\}$ in $\mathbb R -\{0\}$ such that $\{x_n\}$ converges to $0$ but $\{f(x_n)\}$ diverges.

I really can't think of a sequence.  I've tried plotting the function on matlab and it seems to me that if you approach $0$ from either the left or the right then $f(x)$ converges to $0$ so I'm not sure what kind of sequence would diverge.

Comment: $2x+1$ doesn't tend to 0 as you approach 0.

Comment: Oh man you're right. Brain fart. :|

Answer (score 0):

The sequence $\{x_n\} = \{ (-1)^n \frac{1}{n} \}$ would do it. For even $n$, the terms are positive and going to zero, which gives $f(x_{2n}) \to 0$. For odd $n$, the terms are negative and going to zero, which tells us that $f(x_{2n+1}) \to 1$.

Now if the sequence $f(x_n)$ did converge, then every subsequence should converge to the same value. Here we have two subsequences (the evens and odds) that go to two different values. Thus the orginal sequence cannot converge.